# Pandas groupby, loc, forloop and a conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
Class   Rec  Iss   Price Amt  Qtty
 FD      10    0    5     50   10
 FD       0    2    4     -8    8
 RM       5    0    2     10    5
 RM       0    3    3     -9    2
 FD       0    2    2     -4    6
 PM       5    0    3     15    5
 PM       1    0    3      3    6
 RM       1    0    3      3    3
 FD       4    0    2      8    10
```

I require the dataframe below:

```
Class   Rec  Iss   Price Amt  Qtty  WAC
 FD      10    0    5     50   10     5
 FD       0    2    4     -8    8     5
 RM       5    0    2     10    5     2
 RM       0    3    3     -9    2     2
 FD       0    2    2     -4    6     5
 PM       5    0    3     15    5     3
 PM       1    0    3      3    6     3
 RM       1    0    3      3    3   2.3
 FD       4    0    2      8   10   3.8
```

Below is the code i was using when i only had one product class

```
# Set the first average price (We need an inception)
df.loc[0,'WAC'] = df.loc[0,'Price']

# loop over the remaining rows.
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    #if nothing was received, take the previous value
    if df.loc[i, 'Rec'] == 0:
        df.loc[i, 'WAC'] = df.loc[i-1, 'WAC']
    #if something was received
    elif df.loc[i, 'Rec'] > 0:
        df.loc[i, 'WAC'] = (df.loc[i,'Amt'] + ((df.loc[i-1, 'WAC']) * (df.loc[i-1, 'Qtty']))) / (df.loc[i, 'Qtty'])
    elif df.loc[i, 'Rec'] < 0:
        df.loc[i, 'WAC'] = df.loc[i-1, 'WAC']
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'WAC'] = 0
print(df)
```

Now i have to groupby the class before applying my conditions and i don't know how to go about it

Comment: What does "WAC" represent and what are the conditions or rules for calculating it?

Comment: the logic for the computation is in the question @Chowlett2

Comment: @sammywemmy The logic is certainly not in the question. There is some logic in the code sample, but the person asking the question said that their code isn't producing the desired variable so there must be something wrong which they want help with, hence my question.

Comment: it is producing the answer, the OP is asking for a way to scale it to multiple groups. Kindly have a look at the code, test it out

Comment: @sammywemmyperhaps they'll provide some data then, since I can't test it without a sample of their data :)

Comment: the provided dataframe is the data and @andrejkesely has provided an answer; i just feel there can be a better way using vectorized methods, and avoid apply

Comment: @sammywemmy I see they printed out the dataframe but it's really not considerate to force other people to recreate your dataframe themselves just to begin solving their problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible version how you can rewrite your script to be usable with `.groupby`:

```py
def my_func(df):
    # Set the first average price (We need an inception)
    df.loc[df.index[0], "WAC"] = df.loc[df.index[0], "Price"]

    # loop over the remaining rows.
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        # if nothing was received, take the previous value
        if df.loc[df.index[i], "Rec"] == 0:
            df.loc[df.index[i], "WAC"] = df.loc[df.index[i - 1], "WAC"]
        # if something was received
        elif df.loc[df.index[i], "Rec"] > 0:
            df.loc[df.index[i], "WAC"] = (
                df.loc[df.index[i], "Amt"]
                + ((df.loc[df.index[i - 1], "WAC"]) * (df.loc[df.index[i - 1], "Qtty"]))
            ) / (df.loc[df.index[i], "Qtty"])
        elif df.loc[df.index[i], "Rec"] < 0:
            df.loc[df.index[i], "WAC"] = df.loc[df.index[i - 1], "WAC"]
        else:
            df.loc[df.index[i], "WAC"] = 0

    df["WAC"] = df["WAC"].round(1)

    return df


df = df.groupby("Class", group_keys=False).apply(my_func)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Class  Rec  Iss  Price  Amt  Qtty  WAC
0    FD   10    0      5   50    10  5.0
1    FD    0    2      4   -8     8  5.0
2    RM    5    0      2   10     5  2.0
3    RM    0    3      3   -9     2  2.0
4    FD    0    2      2   -4     6  5.0
5    PM    5    0      3   15     5  3.0
6    PM    1    0      3    3     6  3.0
7    RM    1    0      3    3     3  2.3
8    FD    4    0      2    8    10  3.8
```